# Why can't I send companions back to Lucky 38?

Tags: fallout-new-vegas

I used to be able to send companions back to Lucky 38 but all of a sudden I can't any more. I only have the option of ending the companionship rather than sending them to Lucky 38.

Does anyone know why? and how it can be corrected?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the [bugs list for Lucky 38 presidential suite](http://fallout.wikia.com/wiki/Lucky_38_presidential_suite#Companions) on the [FallOut Wikia](http://fallout.wikia.com/wiki/) this is apparently a known bug, unfortunately it seems the only suggested fix requires a certain level of progression in the story line:

> Sometimes, you can lose the option (or
>   never be given the option at all) to
>   tell your companions to wait at the
>   Lucky 38 upon telling them to leave.
>   It appears that if this bug presents
>   itself, you will never be able to ask
>   a companion to wait there for the rest
>   of the game.(Verified, Oct. 31, 2010.)
>   This can be fixed if you kill Mr.
>   House and upload Yes Man into the
>   system.